# How to find Kth smallest number in an array which formed by product of each element of 3 array A,B,C? (Time limit :2s)

Tags: algorithm

[image: Here is the full description of the problem]

The length of each array A,B and C <= 1000 and K <= min(10^6, na * nb * nc) (na,nb,nc is the length of each array A,B and C)

I have thought that we can run through array A and B to find all the products of A and B in O(n^2) and generate Kth number by multiply that products with element in array C. But I don't know how to exactly generate Kth number in step 2th.

In this problem, the number can be NEGATIVE

Does anyone help me about this or give me your idea how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Think of the full list of products as being the union of |A|*|B| lists, each of size |C|. If you sort array C, each of these lists is sorted. Finding the Kth smallest number in a union of a bunch of sorted lists is an easy problem that can be solved using classical multi way merge algorithm.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? I know there is a way to find k th number in two sorted array, but here the number is the product of two array . And here the number can be negative. Sr for not mention that.

Comment: What language are you looking for a solution in?

Comment: I use C++ but I just need an idea !

Comment: I think you're on the right track. break down the arrays one of product of A and B and another C in to two slots, negatives, and positives. Then first consider negative * positive entries from the two interim array and positive * negative entries. 
then try to solve the case that you're given four positive arrays A B , C D you want the kth element in union of [A][B] and [C][D]

Comment: Working on it.... Give me 10 minutes.

Comment: Positive vs. negative does not matter here. More specifically I mean apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Way_Merge_Algorithms#Heap, and to find the Kth smallest element in the union, simply run this algorithm for K iterations. The runtime will be C log C + AB + K*log(AB) = C log C + AB + K*(log A + log B).

Comment: @sukunrt But the maximum element of product array A and B is 1000*1000 = 10 ^ 6. In case the elements in this array are all negative, and the elements in array C are all positive, there will be 10^6 *1000 number if follow your solution. It's too much numbers !

Comment: Oh yes. :( let me think about it a bit

Comment: Okay I think it's done. Let me just add the answer.

Comment: @SnapeSeverus Rishav's answer is correct!

Answer (score 0):

1. Compute `MUL = A[I] * B[J]`, for every `0 <= I < nA`, and `0 <= J < nB`
2. Sort `MUL` and the array `C`.
3. Your full expanded array is then composed of the concatenation of `(nA * nB)` mini-arrays where the *i*th mini-array is generated by multiplying `MUL[i]` with every element of `C`.
4. For each element in MUL, the lowest number in these mini-arrays will be `MUL * C[0]`.
5. Multiply each element of `MUL` by `C[0]`, and put it in a priority queue.
6. Pop `K` times from this list. Each time you pop a number, insert the number you popped multiplied by the next number in `C` (recall that we initially put `MUL * C[0]` into the priority queue), to get the next smallest number in the mini-array generated by this element of `MUL`.

---

```
<!-- language: cpp -->
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int na, nb, nc, K; 
    std::cin >> na >> nb >> nc >> K;
    int a[na], b[nb], c[nc];
    for (int i = 0; i < na; i++) 
        std::cin >> a[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
        std::cin >> b[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nc; i++) {
        std::cin >> c[i];
    }
    std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >, std::greater<std::pair<int, int> > > amulb;
    std::sort(c, c + nc);
    for (int i = 0; i < na; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nb; j++) {
            amulb.push(std::make_pair(a[i] * b[j] * c[0], 0));
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
        std::pair<int, int> t = amulb.top();
        if (i == K - 1) std::cout << t.first << "\n";
        amulb.pop();
        if (t.second != (nc - 1))
            amulb.push(std::make_pair(t.first * c[t.second + 1] / c[t.second], t.second + 1));
    }
    return 0;
}
```